# Nancy framework sample application

Tags: nancy

We are looking to develop a new web application and came across to Nancy fx (actually I am enrolled with Pluralsight where they have a new course on nancy)

I wanted to know a sample application ( one app or separate apps) showing some of features of Nancy Fx

1. Development with Web api (as we have data which come thru web api). Also I want to know does we should have a web api application or there is no need, this can be served by Nancy Fx with one of it extension.
2. Authentication (with restful capability (no need for cookies etc))
3. Can we use third party control like telerik etc with it or not.
4. Can we assign different view for mobile/desktop etc like in asp.net we can have order.mobile.cshtml or even specific to whether its iphone or android etc.

Thanks

Khuzema

Answer (score 13):

Hope you enjoyed the Pluralsight course :-)

Sample wise.. there's small samples inside the main Github repo here: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src

There's a "port" of NerdDinner using Nancy and RavenDb here:

- Demo: http://dinnerparty.azurewebsites.net/
- Source: https://github.com/NancyFx/DinnerParty

There's a new sample that I haven't yet had a chance to look at here:

- Demo: http://people-1.apphb.com/
- Source: https://bitbucket.org/woodwardmatt/people

To answer your questions specifically:

1. You can use Nancy to create a website and a webapi in one site quite easily.
2. There's several different types of authentication supported, the 0.12 release due shortly includes a "stateless" authentication system.
3. Depends what they are, if they're tied specifically to MVC or WebForms then no, if they're client side stuff that uses AJAX then yes.
4. Yes, this has been discussed on the forums with several options: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nancy-web-framework/8MsU4zh2pN8/discussion

Comment: Thanks. Seems Good. Though there will be more question ;)

Comment: demo link http://dinnerparty.azurewebsites.net/ broken now, however source on github is available

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at (yet another) blog site build with NancyFx (using get/post, viewbag, form authentication, testing and other basic staff):

- Source code: https://github.com/itmeze/ITmeze.com
- Demo: http://itmeze.com

Disclaimer: I have made it as a way to get familiar with NancyFX :) And I had fun!